# finding circumradius for cyclic quadilateral given side lengths

Tags: geometry

Suppose a cyclic quadrilateral with sides $a,b,c,d$ is arranged round the circle in that order, say counterclockwise. Is there a formula for the circumradius $R$ in terms of the side lengths?

I found it can be done but needed to assume the two largest sides are adjacent, and then bring in the law of cosines. The result wasn't pretty, relying on finding a diagonal length and then  formula for circumradius of  triangle. My formula did not look very symmetrical, and I didn't like the need for assumptions about how the sides are arranged.

Any response, including reference, appreciated.

Comment: [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Parameshvara's_circumradius_formula)?

Comment: @user647486 Thanks much. A nice symmetric formula.