how do we find the circumradius of a cyclic quadrilateral using its sides and its area

$\square ABCD$ is cyclic. Prove its circumradius $R=\frac{\sqrt{(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}}{4[ABCD]}$

I have tried two methods, using cosine rule on the diagonals, and finding the area of the quadrilateral. Both have not helped progress.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

I searched "circumradius of a cyclic quadrilateral" on google and found this:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicQuadrilateral.html

See also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195365/finding-circumradius-for-cyclic-quadilateral-given-side-lengths

Can you please write out your work or say why it did not work?

i expanded the rhs, ac+bd = fg (product of the diagonals)using ptolemy’s theorem and then multiplied (ab+cd)(ad+cb) and now since 2[ABCD]=fg sinE (E is the angle between the diagonals) the denominator becomes 2fgsinE. after this i couldn’t progress

To obtain this result, you need some prior results on cyclic quadrilaterals. Using $K$ for area, $s$ for semiperimeter, and $l,m,n$ for diagonals :

Brahmagupta's formula: $K^2=(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)$
Ptolemy's theorem: $lm=ab+cd$
Knowledge that for any inscribed convex quadrilateral with sides labeled $a,b,c,d$, the figure may be rearranged within the circle while preserving area with side orders $abcd, acbd, acdb$. To prove this, dissect $ABCD$ on a diagonal $l$, reverse one of the resulting triangles, and replace it on the diagonal $l$. All sides are preserved, one diagonal ($l$) is preserved, the other diagonal vanishes and a new diagonal is introduced. Each figure has $2$ of $3$ possible diagonals, which I'll label $l,m,n$.
This group of area-preserving quadrilaterals leads to a trio of expressions relating diagonals and sides: $abcd: lm=ac+bd, abdc: ln=ad+bc, acbd: mn=ab+cd$
Finally, the area of a triangle $XYZ$ with circumradius $R$ is $\frac{xyz}{4R}$.

Suppose $l,m$ are diagonals for side order $abcd$ with $l$ separating sides $a,b$ and $c,d$. The area of the quadrilateral is the area of the two triangles formed on the diagonal, which have the same circumradius. So $K=\frac{abl}{4R}+\frac{cdl}{4R}=\frac{l(ab+cd)}{4R}$. But now use Ptolemy's Theorem on one of the area-preserving rearrangements of the quadrilateral $acbd$ and diagonals $m,n$, then $mn=ab+cd$ and we have $K=\frac{lmm}{4R}$
So $K^2=\frac{(lmn)^2}{16R^2}=\frac{(lm)(mn)(nl)}{16R^2}=\frac{(ac+bd)(ad+bc)(ab+cd)}{16R^2}$
Set that equal to Brahmagupta's expression for $K^2$ and simplify.

thank you so much

According to this article, a cyclic quadrilateral of sides $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ has a circumradius of $R$ that is given as:
$$
R=\frac 14 \sqrt{\frac{(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}}
$$
